# where / and SQL clause across three tables

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many

why when I add `and` to this query to filter by a tag string I get no results.  How do I 
include this:

```
`subject_tags`.`string_en` =  '%beach%'"
```

properly?

```
SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(22.2863943) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( subject.long ) - radians(114.1491375) ) + sin( radians(22.2863943) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )
AS distance 
FROM subject 
JOIN `subject_to_tag` ON `subject_to_tag`.`subject_id` = `subject`.`id`
JOIN `subject_tags` ON `subject_tags`.`id` = `subject_to_tag`.`tag_id`  
and `subject_tags`.`string_en` =  '%beach%'     
LIMIT 10
```

This is the table structure....

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 2):

For

```
and `subject_tags`.`string_en` =  '%beach%'
```

I think you meant

```
and `subject_tags`.`string_en` LIKE  '%beach%'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the pattern, then you can use "LIKE" operator as Jim Garrison have answered.

```
and `subject_tags`.`string_en` LIKE  '%beach%'
```

But if you want exactly the term "beach" for the column, then you it should be like:

```
and `subject_tags`.`string_en` =  'beach'.
```

Also you can have a look at [Comparison Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html).